# Why am I getting runtime error in this question?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, runtime-error

I was solving a [this question](https://codeforces.com/gym/101853/problem/A) on codeforces. I am getting runtime error in one of their internal test-cases (I am passing their shown test-case). This is my code

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n, nq = map(int, input().strip().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    set_arr = set(arr)
    for j in range(nq):
        q = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        if q[0] is 2:
            if 0 in set_arr:
                print(len(set_arr) - 1)
            else:
                print(len(set_arr))   
        else:
            count = 0
            for k in range(n):
                if arr[k] is arr[q[1] - 1]:
                    count += 1
                if count > 1:
                    break
            if count is 1:
                set_arr.remove(arr[q[1] - 1])

            arr[q[1] - 1] = q[2]
            set_arr.add(q[2])
```

What could be the reason for the runtime error?

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: The full error is not being provided. They're only showing that there is a runtime error. Also, I don't know the test case for which the error occurs.